# Perl for matching with regular expressions in Terminal?

Tags: regex, terminal.app, perl

I'm trying to familiarize myself a little with [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) to use for [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) searches in [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_%28OS_X%29) (Mac). Now, I'm not really looking to learn Perl rigourously, just trying to find out how to do some simple regular expressions.

But I can't figure out how to do this in Terminal:

I'd like to be able to match expressions over several lines, and I'll take [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) tags as an example. PLEASE NOTE, that the HTML tag is just an example of something to match, and specifically something that goes over multiple lines. Whether matching HTML with regular expressionS is a good idea or not is not the issue. I just want to understand the syntax of matching with Perl on the command line!

Say I want to match the entire [ul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Lists) tag here:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to:

1. Be able to match this in a file and output the match to the stdout (don't ask why, I would just want to to understand how it works :-))
2. Be able to replace it with something else.

For matching, I found something like this (using 'start' and 'end' as an example here from a simple text file when I was testing, but please give the example for the `ul` tag instead:

```
perl -wnE 'say $1 if /(start(.*?)end)/' test.txt
```

This matches a part, but only on one line. Surprisingly, adding the s at the end didn't work to make it "dotall" or "single-line mode", it still just matched one line...

For replacing, I tried something like this:

```
perl -pe 's/start(.*?)end/replacement text/'s test.txt
```

This didn't work either...

Comment: [On parsing HTML with regexes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/49849)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I shouldn't have named my question Matching html tags... That was unfortunate. What I'm really after is how to use perl to match on the command line, and the syntax for it, and also to get matching on several lines to work with the /s option...

Comment: Edited my question accordingly!

Comment: [On parsing HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272), mark 2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, here's a wikipedia page for matching or replacing with [Perl one liners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program#Perl). I did this in [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin):

Perl can behave like grep or like sed.

The `/s` makes dot match new line.

The `-0777` makes it apply the regular expression to the whole thing instead of line by line.

`\n` can match new line as well.

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -0777 -pe 's/.*c//s'

d

user@comp ~
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -pe 's/.*c//s'
a
b

d
```

Here is the other form, `-ne` with `print $1`:

```
user@comp ~
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -ne 'print $1 if /(.*c)/s'
c
user@comp ~
$ echo -e 'a\nb\nc\nd' | perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /(.*c)/s'
a
b
c
user@comp ~
$
```

Also

```
$ echo xxx|perl -lne 'print ""'
```

Perl's equivalent of \0 or &, i.e. the whole match is $_ or to be able to put text before and after without a space, ${_}

```
$ echo xxx|perl -lne 'print "a${_}${_}a"'
axxxxxxa
```

and

```
$  echo xxx|perl -lpe 's/.*/a${_}${_}a"/'
axxxxxxa"
```

###Some further examples

```
$ cat t.t
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /\<ul\>(.*?)\<\/ul>/s' t.t

 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>

user@comp ~
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /(.*)/s' t.t
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

user@comp ~
$
```

An example of Global for the `-ne` one (change "if" to "while"):

```
$ echo -e 'bbb' | perl -0777 -ne 'print $1 while /(b)/sg'
bbb
```

For the `-pe` one, just add the `g` at the end (`/sg` or `/gs`, same thing):

```
$  echo -e 'aaa' | perl -0777 -pe 's/a/z/s'
zaa

user@comp ~
$  echo -e 'aaa' | perl -0777 -pe 's/a/z/sg'
zzz
```

Note- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875838/can-these-two-regex-expressions-ever-give-a-different-result) contrasts /s and -0777

Those `print $1` examples don't show the whole line.  this link  https://dzone.com/articles/perl-as-a-better-grep has this example that does  `perl -wln -e "/RE/ and print;" foo.txt`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Just a minor question: why -0777? I thought the s option at the end was supposed to take care of making it match "DOTALL" and therefore include everything (possibly with a g option to take more than one match)?

Comment: i've just updated it for some global examples.  There is a difference between dot matches new line, and having the regex apply to the whole thing.  If you don't have -0777 then the only new line dot could ever see, would be the \n at the end of the line but it won't see past that.  Similarly without -0777, the only new line \n could match, is the only one that is there, which is the \n at the end of one line. It won't see past that, as the regex is only being applied line by line. So you can have any combination of "dot matches new line"(or not).  And -0777 (or not).

Comment: @AndersSvensson  yeah I could see that before, you getting an answer that actually replied to your question properly wasn't looking promising! Removing the HTML might've made the question more idiot proof

Comment: @AndersSvensson To make a further point, just recently, over here I ask a similar question that you ask.. about the difference between -0777 and /s (because I momentarily forgot!). Check the answer given by qtax but also check my answer to my own question.. as it gives examples demonstrating the difference between /s and -0777 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875838/can-these-two-regex-expressions-ever-give-a-different-result

Comment: i'm thinking the -ne print isn't that needed as one has grep which people still use. But the -pe is well needed to replace sed.