# sed regex pattern matched greedy although it should not

Tags: regex, sed, xml, ant

I stumbled upon a behaviour I can not explain, hope some of you guys can help me out.

I try to generate a sort of documentation from a bigger `Ant` project, as such I use `sed` to filter the information from the files, that i need in the documentation later.

I have a normal ant buildfile with lines like this:

```
    <target name="targetA" depends="targetD" description="some fancy description">
...
    <target name="targetB" depends="targetD" description="some fancy description">
...
    <target name="targetC" depends="targetD" description="some fancy description">
```

Now I run along with this sed line:

```
sed -nr 's/.*?target name="(.*?)".*="(.*?)".*/ * \1 - \2/p'
```

It should give me:

```
 * targetA - some fancy description
 * targetB - some fancy description
 * targetC - some fancy description
```

Instead I get:

```
 * targetA" depends="targetD" - some fancy description
 * targetA" depends="targetD" - some fancy description
 * targetA" depends="targetD" - some fancy description
```

I tried skipping the output of the second group to verify that it is the first group that actually matches the whole "depends" part with it, although I set the regex to be non-greedy till the next double-quote.

What am I missing here?

Using a more explicit regex like this works like expected but I still don't get the greedy thing:

```
sed -nr 's/.*?target name="(.*?)".*=.*="(.*?)".*/ * \1 - \2/p'
```

As this might be of interest, I'm using sed-4.2.2-4ubuntu1 on ubuntu linux (default install)

Comment: sed regexes are a bit limited, more limited than greps. if you know regex you can do a perl one liner http://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-terminal   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794145/perl-one-liner-like-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sed does not support non-greedy matches as seen in ".*?" expression.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sed#Limitations)

Try this:

```
sed -nr 's/.*target name="([^"]*)" .*="(.*)".*/ * \1 - \2/p' file
```

Output:

```
 * targetA - some fancy description
 * targetB - some fancy description
 * targetC - some fancy description
```

Comment: Seems a bit round the invisble corner, but really works. Thank you!