# How to insert a newline for every occurrence of the word abstract_ using BATCH

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have an xml I need to edit using batch. How do you insert a newline for every occurrence of the word **abstract_** in the whole file?

Here's a line in the xml (9999999x.xml)

```
<related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999999_abstract_ddd.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999988_abstract_ddd.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999977_abstract_ddd.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999966_abstract_ddd.jpg"/>
```

What I wanted to look like...

```
<related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999999_abstract_
ddd.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999988_abstract_
ded.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999977_abstract_
dfd.jpg"/><related-object content-type="image.extract" object-type="image/jpeg" specific-use="data" xlink:href="99999966_abstract_
dgd.jpg"/>
```

It doesn't have to overwrite the file, it just have to be saved in another text or temp file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/abstract_/abstract_\n/g' 9999999x.xml > 9999999xa.xml
```

`sed` is a weird `unix` editor which few people ever use, *except* to do in-line editing. It comes installed in all distributions.

In this case it takes the input file, and then applies the command between quotes, which tells the editor to substitute `abstract_` by `abstract_\n`. The `g` tells `sed` to go and do it over the entire file.

It types the result to `stdout` which is redirected here to `9999999xa.xml`. Don't redirect to the same file as the input, as that can cause unpredictable results.

**Edit:** We're all so addicted to screen editor, where the text is shown, and you move around and edit what you want.

`sed` is different - you have to know beforehand which commands you are going to apply to the file, and either write them into a 'script' file, or include the commands on the command line itself. Then `sed` will apply those commands in a (mostly) line-by-line based way to the input file.

The title 'in-line-editor' was probably earned by the fact that you can insert `sed` in a command line and use redirection to make it part of the process... An example (which could be optimized):

```
cat some.txt | sed 's/abstract_/abstract_\n/g' | sort
```

So, the text flows from `cat`, through `sed`, to `sort` which is called a pipeline. `sed` is sometime called a stream editor too, for the same reason. Have a look at [the intro for `sed`'s manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction).

Comment: you could also put `\0\n` in the replace section.  One could do use -i for in-place replacement.  `sed -i.bak "s/a/b/g" a.a`  or a bit more risky `sed -i.bak "s/a/b/g" a.a`

Comment: By the way, what does "in-line editing" mean?

Comment: Added some more notes to the answer. They didn't fit here...

Comment: where are you getting the term from?  There is a descroption here of something similar  http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~gc/history/   em was the first to do single line editting. interactivity on a single line. It was an innovation from not seeing the file at all when editing. Though sed isn't a single line editor.  It takes a file as input and runs a script on it affecting many lines.

Comment: When I started programming - way too long ago - I used `ed` (or was it `edlin`?) We actually wrote assembler with that thing, up to 50k lines in one file. I see `sed` as similar - with the difference that it works on streams (and is non-interactive). Where did I really get `in-line`? I can't remember - there are regularly posts that refer to it as such. ([example](http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/09/18/sed-inline-editing-different-on-mac-osx/))

Comment: edlin was 1980-1995, was for DOS before EDIT.COM  I guess only let you edit one line at a time maybe http://allcomputers.us/image/1211/Modifying%20Files%20with%20the%20Edlin%20Utility,%20Repairing%20System%20Databases%20with%20the%20ESEnTUtl%20Utility_1.jpg . http://i.imgur.com/3o08sCB.png    Edit.com came in DOS 5 and 6.    Edit.com was 1995 onwards, definitely full screen edit any line you want, it's still in XP.  .  Ed might've been like 60s maybe 70s.   Which did you learn on?

Comment: This was pre-DOS... Even pre-CP/M. I first programmed on a motorola 6800 development system... Late 70's. (I mean small-system programming. I did program before that - Fortran, PL/I)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a hybrid of batch and javascript where it looks like a batch but it's actually javascript running. jrepl.bat by Dave Benham  **http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044**

Or a third party program like perl or sed. jcop shows re sed.  Sed is old, nowadays people use perl.  This link shows how to convert a search and replace sed line, into perl **[Perl for matching with regular expressions in Terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-terminal)**    But it's OK to use sed.  Sed works line by line, so doesn't support \n in the find section (even the 'latest' version doesn't). But sed(apart from an old version on unxutils) does support it in the replace section which is what you need.  Perl of course supports it in find or replace.

You can get sed from gnuwin32 **http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html**  download sed there, and if doing that then I suggest getting gnuwin32 coreutils too, and whatever others you find you want.

There is an old version of sed from unxutils though I don't suggest that and the old version of sed that unxutils has is GNU sed version 3.02 which doesn't support \n so won't help. There is also a sed on Windows SUA, but that one doesn't support \n either and doesn't even say what version it is.

So get sed from gnuwin32 or cygwin or MinGW or gow. Not SUA and not unxutils.