# Batch file to replace row containing a specific string value

Tags: command-line, batch

I have an interface file for example named RawData.txt which contains different regions of data which can range from a few thousand lines to nearer 100,000 lines of data.

There is a mix of lines which contain for example

***01  00000000000000000000000000000198699  XYZ***

which have int values other than 0 included that at times need to be replaced with

***01  00000000000000000000000000000000000  XYZ***

but due to the variablility of the int value between the 01 and XYZ markers a straight forward find and replace in a text editor will not work.

The part I need to manipulate is structured like below:

```
01  00000000000000000000000000000198699 XYZ

02  157

01  00000000000000000000000000000007749 XYZ

02  158

01  00000000000000000000000000000183279 XYZ

02  163

01  00000000000000000000000000000007749 XYZ

02  165

01  00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  175
```

Ideally I am looking to put together a batch file that searches for any lines in the .txt file starting with the 01 record marker and replaces the line with:

***01  00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ***

I assume the most straight forward approach is to find any lines starting with **01** record marker and replace the whole line as the length needs to be identical after the amendments are made to the existing data.

Most examples I have found related to replacing one string with another as in the example here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614101/batch-script-find-string-in-text-file-by-line-then-replace-whole-line-with-anot?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

but cannot modify to accomplish what I need from a batch file.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your examples show a mixture of one and two spaces between the `01` and the `000...` fields. Which is correct? Can either occur? Does the replacement string require the same number of spaces?

Comment: Oh you'd be amazed how versatile text editors are, because they support regular expressions.  So , in a text editor like notepad++ try ticking a regex checkbox and doing  `[0-9]*` and you will see it will match that string of digits.  But a batch file or any language should be able to do what you want too.

Comment: Apologies the example data is in poor formatting on my part.  There needs to be 2 spaces between the 01 and the large integer string and one space between the integer string and the XYS marker.

Comment: @GrantSDC  ok how about   `@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%f in (a.a) do @IF "%%f"=="01" (echo 01  00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ) ELSE IF NOT "%%f"=="01" ECHO %%f  %%g`

Comment: I also tested a simple example like a file with just the line `abc[multiple spaces]def` and it treats abc as the first token and def as the second. So it counts either a space or a sequence of contiguous spaces, to be a delimiter.   It's worth using simple examples if you want to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want

A batch file dealt with this surprisingly neatly!

Where `a.a` is your data file

blahblah.bat is a one line batch file

```
C:\Users\harvey>type blahblah.bat
@for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%f in (a.a) do @IF "%%f"=="01" (echo 01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ) ELSE IF NOT "%%f"=="01" ECHO %%f %%g

C:\Users\harvey>
```

execute the batch file

```
C:\Users\harvey>blahblah
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ
02 157
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ
02 158
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ
02 163
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ
02 165
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ
02 175

C:\Users\harvey>
```

That did seem to remove blank lines, there may be a way around that with batch, but another way, besides batch, is to use sed.

```
C:\Users\harvey>sed -r "s/^01.*/01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ/" a.a

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  157

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  158

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  163

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  165

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  175
```

You could of course add `>b.b` to redirect that output to a new file, so you could do `sed -r "......." a.a > b.b`   i.e. `sed -r "s/^01.*/01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ/" a.a > b.b`

Comment: Thanks for this barlop.  Having a bit of issue adapting to the full file but this has given me a good place to start with.

Comment: I should note, for longevity, it's worth adapting these sed lines to perl.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794145/perl-one-liner-like-grep  see https://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-terminal   Sed might have issues sometimes, and perl is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to parse the file and keep empty lines is to let the lines be numbered through findstr
(so they aren't empty for the for /f loop)
and discard the number afterwards.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\11\SU_1321271.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal

Set "ZEROES=00000000000000000000000000000000000"

( for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%A in (
    'findstr /N "^" RawData.txt'
  ) do If "%%B"=="01" (
      echo=%%B  %ZEROES% XYZ
  ) else (
      echo=%%B  %%C
  )
) >NewData.txt
```

---

```
> type NewData.txt
01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  157

01 00000000000000000000000000000000000 XYZ

02  158
...
```